# HWIOAuthBundle -> problemi installazione

Tags: installation, hwioauthbundle

il git delle configurazioni eseguite come da documentazione https://gist.github.com/idlweb/6232475

l'errore restituito:
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to replace alias "my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service" with "hwi_oauth.user.provider.entity.secured_area".

grazie per qualsiasi aiuto

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions on StackOverflow need to be in English.

Comment: Re: HWIOAuthBundle have error on service definition
Postby vpatil09 » Tue Aug 14, 2012 1:15 pm

define the service for this in services.yml
CODE: SELECT ALL
services:
    my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
        arguments:
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            properties: ["pass properties as array"]

Answer (score 4):

Try this to get started:

```
security:
    ....
    firewalls:
        ...
        secured_area:
        ...
            oauth:
            ...
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider
```

Answer (score 2):

Re: HWIOAuthBundle have error on service definition
Postby vpatil09 » Tue Aug 14, 2012 1:15 pm

define the service for this in services.yml

```
services:
    my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:
        class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider
        arguments:
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            properties: ["pass properties as array"]
```